# Reload options for the ui.select

Tags: javascript, html, html-select, webix

I already know how to redefine the options for the Webix ui.rixhselect/ui.combo. Basically, it looks like:

```
richselect.getList().clearAll();   
richselect.getList().parse(options_data)
```

But how can I change options for the ui.select? Using the same methods for it, I get the following error: "*Uncaught TypeError: $$(...).getList is not a function*":

http://webix.com/snippet/e8e9a469

How can I load new options into the ui.select? Thanks in advance.

Comment: ui.select is just an html-based control and doesn't provide such features (loading list).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
richselect.define("options", newdata);
richselect.render();
```

.render API will repaint the control with new set of options